# Reducing Code Duplication with For loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, duplicates

```
    for (Aircraft aircraft : landingQueue) {
        if (aircraft.hasEmergency()) {
            return aircraft;
        }
    }

    for (Aircraft aircraft : landingQueue) {
        if (aircraft.getFuelPercentRemaining() <= 20) {
            return aircraft;
        }
    }

    for (Aircraft aircraft : landingQueue) {
        if (aircraft instanceof PassengerAircraft) {
            return aircraft;
        }
    }
    return landingQueue.get(0);
```

So my program runs through a list of aircraft in a queue and will return one based on the importance of a task. For instance, it will first check the landingQueue ArrayList to see if any aircraft are in an emergency and if it can't find one it then checks for aircraft with fuel less than 20 and so on. Is there a simple way to reduce the duplication of the for loop and if statement? Much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Another approach could be to sort your list according to your priority criteria

```
public Aircraft returnOneBasedOnImportance(){
    Comparator<Aircraft> byEmer = Comparator.comparing(a -> !a.hasEmergency());
    Comparator<Aircraft> byFuel = Comparator.comparing(a -> !(a.getFuelPercentRemaining() <= 20));
    Comparator<Aircraft> byType = Comparator.comparing(a -> !(a instanceof PassengerAircraft));

    return landingQueue.stream()
                       .sorted(byEmer.thenComparing(byFuel).thenComparing(byType))
                       .findFirst().get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The improvement is not as much about code duplication, more important it is to limit the number of times you iterate through that list.

```java
Aircraft firstEmergencyAircraft = null;
Aircraft firstLowFuelAircraft = null;
Aircraft firstPassengerAircraft = null;

for (Aircraft aircraft : landingQueue) {
        if (firstEmergencyAircraft==null && aircraft.hasEmergency()) {
            firstEmergencyAircraft = aircraft;
        }
        if (firstLowFuelAircraft==null && aircraft.getFuelPercentRemaining() <= 20) {
            firstLowFuelAircraft = aircraft;
        }
        if (firstPassengerAircraft==null && aircraft instanceof PassengerAircraft) {
            firstPassengerAircraft = aircraft;
        }
    }

if(firstEmergencyAircraft!=null){
    return firstEmergencyAircraft;
}
if(firstLowFuelAircraft!=null){
    return firstLowFuelAircraft;
}
if(firstPassengerAircraft!=null){
    return firstPassengerAircraft;
}
return landingQueue.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make landingQueue some sort of SortedSet (i.e. TreeSet) with a Comparator that sorts by landing priority (i.e. sort criteria are emergency, low fuel level, is PassangerAircraft). Then you can always just pick the first (or last) entry from the list.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a stream of predicates first, then for each predicate loop through the list and try to find an aircraft that matches. If no match is found, return the first element.

```
Stream<Predicate<Aircraft>> predicates = Stream.of(
  (aircraft) -> aircraft.hasEmergency(),
  (aircraft) -> aircraft.getFuelPercentRemaining() <= 20,
  (aircraft) -> aircraft instanceof PassengerAircraft
);

return predicates
  .flatMap((predicate) -> landingQueue.stream().filter(predicate))
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(landingQueue.get(0));
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not just do the tests in one loop?

```
for (Aircraft aircraft : landingQueue) {
    if (aircraft.hasEmergency() ||
        aircraft.getFuelPercentRemaining() <= 20 ||
        aircraft instanceof PassengerAircraft) {
        return aircraft;
    }
}

return landingQueue.get(0);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this change the logic? It should first check if there is any aircraft that has an emergency, now it will return any aircraft that matches any of the conditions.

Comment: Changes logic just like in QBrute's answer

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation and 15.24 of the Java Language Specification (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24). Boolean operands are evaluated in order and will short circuit.

Comment: Suppose the second item in the `landingQueue` is a passenger aircraft, but has no emergency. The fifth item has emergency, but is not a passenger aircraft, and all aircrafts have more than 20 fuel. Your algorithm will return the second item in the queue, but OP's code will return the fifth item.

Comment: I considered deleting my answer now that I realize it is wrong. I am leaving it here to help others see the logic error. I recommend that everyone read @Eritrean's answer as that is correct and the most elegant, in my opinion.